# Special Characters in App Name

Tags: iphone, xcode, app-store

I would like to use a special character in the name of my app (é to be precise). When using the name for the Xcode project, strange things happen. So I thought I could name the project something else, without the special character. The real name though should still appear on the iPhone, in iTunes and in the App Store. So my question is: Is it enough to change the *Bundle display name* property? As far as I know, the App Store name can be set when the app is sent to Apple, is this correct?

I would appreciate some help, Fabian

Comment: What "strange things" happen? I have an app in the store, with an `é` in it and everything's working fine.

Comment: The version control included in Xcode 4 doesn't recognize some files anymore. Also, some files seem to be named in a strange way, using `_` or `-` instead of `é`.

Comment: @fabian789: You can rename these files manually.

Comment: I think this is of topic, although there is no other place for this question, so I'm not voting to close.

Comment: I've just set up this proposal for app store questions. See it here: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30702/app-store

Comment: @Moshe That would be a good idea!

Comment: This is on topic.  It's not any different than a question about setting up an installation program so your software installs correctly.  The app store is merely a corporate installation program.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Bundle display name is what actually shows up on user's devices.

Yes, it can be CLOSE TO the "official" app name.

It does not have to be **absolutely identical**, so you don't have to panic about accents, etc.

(If it is **very different**, Apple will reject it.)

For example, it's normal to have reasonable abbreviations, and there would be no problem if you had for example accents in one and not the other.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem because I wanted to add a ™ symbol after my app name.  When you're putting in your Application Name in iTunes Connect, it accepts special characters.  To do one, with your cursor in the text box on the web page, select `Edit -> Special Characters...` and select your character.